# Как реализовать функцию throttle?

Tags: javascript

Функция должна принимать функцию и время задержки, а возвращать модифицированную функцию. Полученная функция должна следовать следующим правилам:

Функция throttle должна вызывать функцию и запускать таймер, равный времени задержки, в течение которого функция не может быть вызвана заново. Throttle необходим для того, чтобы обеспечить возможность вызова функции не чаще, чем указанное время задержки. Если время задержки равно 500 мс, то при вызове функции, возвращенной из throttle, каждые 100 мс 10 раз подряд функция будет вызвана лишь три раза:
первый вызов функции на 0мс (первая попытка вызова функции после 0 мс задержки),
второй на 500 мс (пятая попытка вызова функции после 500 мс задержки)
и третий на 1000 мс (десятая попытка вызова функции после 1000 мс задержки).
Пример throttle:

```
let counter = 0;
const fn = () => {
  counter++;
};

const throttledFn = throttle(fn, 500); // функция может быть вызвана не чаще, чем раз в 500 мс

const intervalId = setInterval(throttledFn, 100);
setTimeout(() => clearInterval(intervalId), 1000); // удаляем интервал через 10 вызовов

console.log(counter); // 3
```

Я попытался реализовать двумя способами.

Первый вариант:

```
const throttle = (fn, throttleTime) => {
    let start = -Infinity;
    let cachedResult;

    return function() {
        const end = Date.now();
        
        if (end - start >= throttleTime) {
            start = end;
            cachedResult = fn();
        }
        
        return cachedResult;
    };
}
```

не проходит тест:

```
✓ должна позволять вызывать функцию не чаще, чем один раз в указанный промежуток времени (9ms)
✕ должна передать контекст вызова и аргументы throttled-функции в оригинальную функцию (8ms)
```

Второй вариант:

```
const throttle = (fn, throttleTime) => {
    let isThrottled = false;
    let isFirstCall = true;
  
    return function() {
        if (isFirstCall) {
            isFirstCall = false;
            return fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
    
        if (isThrottled) return;
    
        isThrottled = true;
    
        setTimeout(() => {
            fn.apply(this, arguments);
            isThrottled = false;
        }, throttleTime)
    }
}
```

Тут уже второй тест прошел, а первый нет:

```
 ✕ должна позволять вызывать функцию не чаще, чем один раз в указанный промежуток времени (22ms)
 ✓ должна передать контекст вызова и аргументы throttled-функции в оригинальную функцию (6ms)
```

Comment: В первом варианте ошибка тут: `cachedResult = fn();` должно быть `cachedResult = fn.apply(this, arguments);` Во второй попытке - вроде все условия выполнены, надо знать, где тестили и как.

Comment: Спасибо, решил, и только потом увидел коммит)

Answer (score 5):

решил задачу

```
const throttle = (fn, throttleTime) => {
    let start = -Infinity;
    let cachedResult;

    return function() {
        const end = Date.now();
        
        if (end - start >= throttleTime) {
            start = end;
            cachedResult = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        
        return cachedResult;
    };
}
```

Comment: прими свой ответ

Answer (score 1):

```
const throttle = (fn, throttleTime) => {
    let isThrottled = false

    return function() {
        if (isThrottled) return

        fn.apply(this, arguments)

        isThrottled = true
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            isThrottled = false
        }, throttleTime)

    }
};
```